# display a plotly html file as image inside reactstrap card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, reactstrap

Currently my website displays plots with info using reactstrap cards. Recently, I found out that instead of saving plotly graphs to png/pdf, saving as html is much faster to process, so I wanted to move to html instead. The old version of the card looks like this:

```
const Plot = ({name, pngUri, pdfUri, search, display, onHover}) => {
  return (
    <Card className={cx(plotSty, display ? null : hidden)} onMouseEnter={onHover}>
      <a href={pdfUri} target="_blank">
        <CardHeader>{hlSearch(name, search)}</CardHeader>
        <CardImg src={pngUri} />
      </a>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

I was able to get it to display if I get rid of `<Card>` and instead use `<iframe>` but that means I lose the ability to search through plots and set some of them to not display on the page.

Is there a way to display the html plots while still keeping the  card functionalities? Is there perhaps a different library I can use for this?

The plotly graphs are made with plotly in python backend.

example of plotly html files can be found here: https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/

Comment: Why not just a <div> ? In the backend code you could use `fig.to_html(full_html=False)` which will produce a string containing a single <div> element.